# except versus raise exception

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I am watching Introduction To Computer Science And Programming In Python and I can't understand well class 7 topic around exceptions. There are two sample code provided

```
    try:
    a = int(input("Tell me one number: "))
    b = int(input("Tell me another number: "))
    print("a/b = ", a/b)
except:
    print("Bug in user input.")


try:
    a = int(input("Tell me one number: "))
    b = int(input("Tell me another number: "))
    print("a/b = ", a/b)
    print("a+b = ", a+b)
except ValueError:
    print("Could not convert to a number.")
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Can't divide by zero")
except:
    print("Something went very wrong.")
```

and

```
def get_ratios(L1, L2):
    """ Assumes: L1 and L2 are lists of equal length of numbers
        Returns: a list containing L1[i]/L2[i] """
    ratios = []
    for index in range(len(L1)):
        try:
            ratios.append(L1[index]/L2[index])
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            ratios.append(float('nan')) #nan = Not a Number
        except:
            raise ValueError('get_ratios called with bad arg')
        else:
            print("success")
        finally:
            print("executed no matter what!")
    return ratios
    
print(get_ratios([1, 4], [2, 4]))
```

I tried

```
except ValueError:
                print('get_ratios called with bad arg')
```

inside the function in the second piece of code but it doesnt work. Overall, I can't understand very well the difference between this two things. I tried to find explanations online and read some analogy to throwing and catching balls but it did not clarify much for me.

Would any of you would be able to explain with example code so I can look to the output and try to understand this?

Thank you, much appreciated

Comment: Are you aware that a bare `except:` catches *all* exceptions?

Comment: `raise` is used with a condition (such as x < 0) along the lines of `if condition: raise ValueError('message')` not as part of a `try_ except` block. It will then stop the code execution.

Comment: The distinction is simple. `raise` will crash the program. `print()` on `except` will just keep running

Comment: `raise` does not crash a program; it raises an exception. If the exception remains *uncaught* by your program, the interpreter will exit with a traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The

```py
except:
    raise ValueError('get_ratios called with bad arg')
```

**raise the `ValueError` in every other Exception case.**

In this case, when you use the second code, it raise a `TypeError` not, `ValueError`. However, TypeError is different from "successful" source code, and also different from `ZeroDivisionError`, but it a `Exception`. So the code will raise the `TypeError`. (Cause you never except this `TypeError`).

For the first version, the code does not mind whether your `ratios.append(L1[index]/L2[index])` is which kind of `Error`, the code will always run into the `raise ValueError('get_ratios called with bad arg')` lines. Try to replace the term with following code to see the different

```py
def get_ratios(L1, L2):
    """ Assumes: L1 and L2 are lists of equal length of numbers
        Returns: a list containing L1[i]/L2[i] """
    ratios = []
    for index in range(len(L1)):
        try:
            ratios.append(L1[index]/L2[index])
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            ratios.append(float('nan')) #nan = Not a Number
        except TypeError:
            print("Your code ran in to the TypeError")
        except ValueError:
            print("something")

        else:
            print("success")
        finally:
            print("executed no matter what!")
    return ratios

-----------

def get_ratios(L1, L2):
    """ Assumes: L1 and L2 are lists of equal length of numbers
        Returns: a list containing L1[i]/L2[i] """
    ratios = []
    for index in range(len(L1)):
        try:
            ratios.append(L1[index]/L2[index])
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            ratios.append(float('nan')) #nan = Not a Number
        except TypeError:
            print("Your code ran in to the TypeError")
        except:
            print("something")

        else:
            print("success")
        finally:
            print("executed no matter what!")
    return ratios
```